# How to decode List of 0s and 1s by List of positions of 1?

Tags: scala

I want to create an `List[Int]` containing only 0 and 1. Position of zeros and ones defined in  array

```
val bitMask = List(2,5,6,11,...,621,655)
```

`bitMask` - is list of position ones in result list, over items of resulting list is zeros

as a result I want to get

```
result = List(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,...,0,1)
```

Length the result to calculated as `bitMask.last + 1`

I did it using this code:

```
result = List.fill(bitMask.last+1)(0).zipWithIndex.map(i => if (bitMask.contains(i._2)) 1 else 0)
```

May have a more simple and more scala-way solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BitSet will provide more efficient look ups (in fact, it is superior if you want to work with unions, distinctions and so on):

```
val mask = scala.collection.BitSet(2,5,6,11)
(0 to 100).map(mask)
// Vector(false, false, true, false, false, ...)
```

Conversion from Boolean to 0/1 should be trivial

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version with a mutable collection ([Array](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array))

```
scala> val bitMask = List(2,5,6,11,15)
bitMask: List[Int] = List(2, 5, 6, 11, 15)

scala> bitMask.foldLeft(Array.fill(bitMask.last+1)(0)){ (arr, x) => arr(x) = 1; arr }.toList
res0: List[Int] = List(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the following one-liner?

```
scala> val bitMask = List(2,5,6,11)
bitMask: List[Int] = List(2, 5, 6, 11)

scala> bitMask.foldLeft(List.empty[Int]) { (r, e) => r ++ Seq.fill(e - r.size)(0) ++ Seq(1) }
res0: List[Int] = List(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```