# Scala creating a list with some data at specific indices and 0 at all the rest indices

Tags: list, scala, immutability, scala-2.10

I have a list named `positiveDays` which contains values (2,4,6) and I want to create a list `DaysDetails` having value of 1 at all the `positiveDays` indices and 0 at the rest indices.

Example -

```
positiveDays(2,4,6)
```

O/p List -> `DaysDetails(0,0,1,0,1,0,1)`

Can anyone suggest me a way to do that without use of var?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820695/how-to-decode-list-of-0s-and-1s-by-list-of-positions-of-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (only when `positiveDays` List is not empty):

```
val positiveDays = List(2,4,6)
List.tabulate(1 + positiveDays.last) {
  pos => if (positiveDays.contains(pos)) 1 else 0 
}
```

To correctly handle the case when `positiveDays` is empty you could use:

```
List.tabulate(positiveDays.lastOption.fold(0)(1 + _)) {
  pos => if (positiveDays.contains(pos)) 1 else 0 
}
```

Comment: need to change the positiveDays.last to positiveDays.last+1

Thanks

Comment: Note that the `last` method will throw an exception if the list is empty - `scala> List().last
java.util.NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Thanks! I added an alternate version to handle empty list case.

Comment: What if `positiveDays` has `-42` in it?

Comment: What does it mean? Does it set a new low bound of the result list (`-42` instead of `0`)?  Note that current solution does not work if `positiveDays` is not sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your "special" day numbers into list and then map all week days with check if it's one of your "special" day.

```
val positiveDays = List(2,4,6)

(0 to 6) map { i =>
  if (positiveDays.contains(i)) 1
  else 0
}

res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
```

Of course, if you are only interested in even days, then you can make it like that:

```
  (0 to 6) map { i =>
    if (i % 2 == 0) 1
    else 0
  }
```

And if you want to start your week with Monday, not Sunday, then use `1 to 7` instead of `0 to 6`.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to skin this particular cat, but I think this one is succinct and quite clear:

```
val positiveDays = Set(2,3,6)
for (i<- 0 to 6)
  yield if (positiveDays(i)) 1 else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using `Int`'s to represent days of the week is wrong. There's `Int.MinValue + Int.MaxValue` `Int`'s, but 7 days of the week.

What day of the week does `666` represent? How about `-42`?

```
scala> sealed trait DayOfWeek
defined trait DayOfWeek

scala> case object Monday extends DayOfWeek
defined object Monday

scala> case object Tuesday extends DayOfWeek
defined object Tuesday

// I excluded the rest for conciseness

scala> val positiveDays: List[DayOfWeek] = List(Tuesday)
positiveDays: List[DayOfWeek] = List(Tuesday)

scala> val AllDays: List[DayOfWeek] = List(Monday, Tuesday) 
AllDays: List[DayOfWeek] = List(Monday, Tuesday)

scala> AllDays.map(d => if (positiveDays.contains(d)) (d, 1) else (d,0) )
res0: List[(DayOfWeek, Int)] = List((Monday,0), (Tuesday,1))
```